# Courier-IMAP pop3d auth over mysql

Tags: mysql, pop3, courier-imap

I've got a task of migrating one mail server from one box to another and so far I have configured `Postfix` and it's working. But, Courier `pop3d` server fails without exception.

So, I have Courier `pop3d` server which needs to authenticate user agains `MySQL` database.

**<kbd>/var/log/maillog</kbd>**

```
Oct 20 03:40:09 vps-1161420-22112 pop3d: Connection, ip=[::ffff:127.0.0.1]
Oct 20 03:40:15 vps-1161420-22112 pop3d: LOGIN: ip=[::ffff:127.0.0.1], command=USER
Oct 20 03:40:21 vps-1161420-22112 pop3d: LOGIN: ip=[::ffff:127.0.0.1], command=PASS
Oct 20 03:40:21 vps-1161420-22112 pop3d: LOGIN: ip=[::ffff:127.0.0.1], username=noreply@domain.tld
Oct 20 03:40:21 vps-1161420-22112 pop3d: LOGIN: ip=[::ffff:127.0.0.1], password=some-foo
Oct 20 03:40:21 vps-1161420-22112 authdaemond: received auth request, service=pop3, authtype=login
Oct 20 03:40:21 vps-1161420-22112 authdaemond: authmysql: trying this module
Oct 20 03:40:21 vps-1161420-22112 authdaemond: stopping authdaemond children
Oct 20 03:40:21 vps-1161420-22112 authdaemond: restarting authdaemond children
Oct 20 03:40:21 vps-1161420-22112 authdaemond: modules="authmysql", daemons=5
Oct 20 03:40:21 vps-1161420-22112 authdaemond: Uninstalling authmysql
Oct 20 03:40:21 vps-1161420-22112 authdaemond: Installing libauthmysql
Oct 20 03:40:21 vps-1161420-22112 authdaemond: Installation complete: authmysql
Oct 20 03:40:22 vps-1161420-22112 pop3d: LOGIN FAILED, user=noreply@domain.tld, ip=[::ffff:127.0.0.1]
Oct 20 03:40:22 vps-1161420-22112 pop3d: authentication error: Input/output error
```

The last two lines of don't say much on what could the IO error actually be.

I have configured mysql connection within file: `/etc/authlib/authmysqlrc`:

```
MYSQL_SERVER            localhost
MYSQL_USERNAME          postfix
MYSQL_PASSWORD          some-password
....
other mysql settings
```

I have verified that I can connect to `MySQL` itself using there credentials.

So, is there some way to increace verbosity of `pop3d` or `authmysql`? I have set `DEBUG_LOGIN=2` in `authdaemonrc` file.

Thank a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this myself.

The key issue is that I built `courier-authlib`binaries on my dev box **but** my production box had `mysql-5.5.*` and my dev box had `mysql-5.6.*`.

Obviously, the difference between lib files caused the `authmysql` to crash when invoked...

Hope this will be helpful to someone...